# Arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management values do not match values found via ArcCatalog or ArcView

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy, arccatalog

I am using Arcpy to extract the mean and standard deviation values of tiff Landsat satellite images and I get very high values. Values in the thousands rather than in the low hundreds! If I look at the same images via properties in ArcCatalog or ArcView I get reasonable values that I would expect.

Question is, why am I seeing different values and how can I get the correct values using arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management? Has anyone seen this before?

Example:

```
>>> arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(zeronodat1, "STD", "Band_1")
<Result '5505.54904039909'>
```

actual values = 5.072720773551549

Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot this are welcomed.

Comment: I welcome any ideas for this!

Answer (score 1):

I have 10.2, which version of ArcGIS do you have (you should always quote that)?

Anyway just tested the tool against the arcpy method and both return the same value for me. Did you actually set the band number as you did in the arcpy method? The only thing I would suggest is to recompute the statistics, maybe they have become corrupted in same way?

Comment: Hornbydd I am using version 10.1 SP1.